# Potential XSS bug in email form?

Tags: xss

I have a invite users via email form on my website and I was wondering if this could be a potential XSS flaw?

I captured the request via Burp, and this is how it looks:

Input:

```
{
"toEnvWithEmail":"<script>alert(1)</script>",
"inviteEmails":["dsadasdas@gmail.com"]
}
```

Output:

```
{
"message":"400 BAD_REQUEST \"no user with email <script>alert(1)</script>\"","error":"Bad Request","timestamp":"2023-12-01T18:14:18.528482500Z","status":400
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Is this from a decoded JWT?

Comment: Does the reflection happen? In other words, does the alert pop up?

Comment: On the website no , but on the BURP the alert shows up as per the above if you see the request and response

Comment: looks like you are reflecting user input in your error response...  the "no user with email" bit.

Comment: @pcalkins yes that is correct , can this lead to potential reflected XSS?

Comment: maybe... better to use a more generic error message.